# Creating an .ipa from .app for iOS using CMake

Tags: ios, cmake

I am using CMake for my builds for iOS/iPadOS/tvOS etc. When `add_executable` is done with MACOSX_BUNDKE, CMake generates a `.app`. Is there a way I can generate a `.ipa` once `.app` is available or directly through CMake?